# Determine days lapsed for each calendar year given start dates and end dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently stuck with a task which is to find out the number of days remaining in each calendar year with given a start date and an end date. I am able to do for one date but not if I were to calculate for multiple start dates and end dates in a table.

**Challenge**: given a table with start dates and end dates, find out the days have lapsed in each calendar years.

Expected output:

Table A

| No | StartDT | EndDT | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | ........ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-01-05 | 2020-03-31 | 0 | 0 | 360 | 365 | 365 | 90 |  |
| 2 | 2015-04-25 | 2018-10-03 | 251 | 366 | 365 | 276 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: it is easy if you have a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: The fact that you want a different column for every year is problematic. Presumably, the columns therefore need dynamic columns? If so, I would strongly suggest you rethink this; or at least rethink the requirement to pivot your data in the SQL layer.

Comment: Thanks both. The reason why I am doing this is that I would like to calculate the proportion for the number of days in each calendar so that I can use them for further calculation. Any thoughts to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks a little like homework... what have you tried so far? However, following an example which might help you finding the solution - if you use pivot on the result, it should look pretty much like your expected result. ;-)

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATE = '2017-01-05';
DECLARE @EndDT DATE = '2020-03-31';

WITH cteYears AS(
SELECT @StartDT AS StartDT, @EndDT AS EndDT, YEAR(@StartDT) AS y
UNION ALL
SELECT StartDT, EndDT, y+1
  FROM cteYears
  WHERE y < YEAR(EndDT)
)
SELECT *
      ,CASE
         WHEN y = YEAR(StartDT) THEN DATEDIFF(d, StartDT, CAST(CAST(YEAR(StartDT) AS VARCHAR(8)) + '-12-31' AS DATE))                     
         WHEN y = YEAR(EndDT) THEN DATEDIFF(d, CAST(CAST(YEAR(EndDT) AS VARCHAR(8)) + '-01-01' AS DATE), EndDT)
         ELSE DATEDIFF(d, CAST(CAST(YEAR(y) AS VARCHAR(8)) + '-01-01' AS DATE), CAST(CAST(YEAR(y) AS VARCHAR(8)) + '-12-31' AS DATE))+1
       END AS DiffDays
  FROM cteYears
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pivot over the years you want to aggregate for, and in order to determine which years you need to pivot over you must use dynamic SQL.

I defined a table variable called @daterange which contains a list of different start/end dates, including your example dates. I also defined a user defined type (called DateRangeType) so that this table variable can be sent to sp_executesql as a parameter.

Note I also included a PRINT statement, so you can see what SQL is being created and stick it in a query window, to help understand what it is doing with nice formatting (not just a big block of string).

```
IF NOT EXISTS (   SELECT *
                  FROM   sys.types AS t
                  WHERE  t.name = 'DateRangeType')
    CREATE TYPE DateRangeType AS TABLE (
        startdate DATE NOT NULL
       ,enddate   DATE NOT NULL
    );
GO

DECLARE @daterange DateRangeType;

DECLARE @yearselect NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
       ,@yearpvt NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
       ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

INSERT INTO @daterange (startdate
                       ,enddate)
VALUES ('2017-01-05', '2020-03-31')
      ,('2015-04-25', '2018-10-03');

WITH years
AS (SELECT YEAR(d.startdate) AS eachyear
          ,YEAR(d.enddate) AS endyear
    FROM   @daterange AS d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.eachyear + 1
          ,y.endyear
    FROM   years AS y
    WHERE  y.eachyear < y.endyear)
SELECT   @yearselect += CONCAT(',ISNULL(pvt.', QUOTENAME(years.eachyear), ',0) AS ', QUOTENAME(years.eachyear))
        ,@yearpvt += CONCAT(',', QUOTENAME(years.eachyear))
FROM     years
GROUP BY years.eachyear
ORDER BY years.eachyear;

SELECT @yearselect = STUFF(@yearselect, 1, 1, '')
      ,@yearpvt = STUFF(@yearpvt, 1, 1, '');

SELECT @sql = CONCAT(
                  N'WITH years
AS (SELECT d.startdate
          ,d.enddate
          ,YEAR(d.startdate) AS eachyear
          ,YEAR(d.enddate) AS endyear
    FROM   @daterange AS d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.startdate
          ,y.enddate
          ,y.eachyear + 1
          ,y.endyear
    FROM   years AS y
    WHERE  y.eachyear < y.endyear)
SELECT   pvt.startdate
        ,pvt.enddate
        ,'
                 ,@yearselect
                 ,'
FROM     (   SELECT years.startdate
                   ,years.enddate
                   ,years.eachyear
                   ,DATEDIFF(DAY
                            ,CASE YEAR(years.startdate)
                                 WHEN years.eachyear THEN years.startdate
                                 ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(years.eachyear, 1, 1)
                             END
                            ,CASE YEAR(years.enddate)
                                 WHEN years.eachyear THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,years.enddate)
                                 ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(years.eachyear + 1, 1, 1)
                             END) AS dayselapsed
             FROM   years) AS y
PIVOT (   MAX(dayselapsed)
          FOR eachyear IN ('
                 ,@yearpvt
                 ,')) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.startdate DESC
        ,pvt.enddate DESC;');

PRINT (@sql);

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql
                      ,@params = N'@daterange DateRangeType READONLY'
                      ,@daterange = @daterange;
GO

DROP TYPE DateRangeType;
GO
```

This is not a particularly pretty solution, but it is really not a very pretty problem... Ideally this pivot should be done in the layer that is calling this sql rather than in the sql itself.

Hope it helps though!

Comment: Oh and you may notice the results of two cells are different from your "expected output", but I think this is because they are wrong in the question. The results for StartDT = 2017-01-05 for 2017 and 2020 should be 361 (including the first day) and 91 (leap year) respectively.